# laravel 5.4 upload image

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

My controller code for upload file in laravel 5.4:

```
if ($request->hasFile('input_img')) {
    if($request->file('input_img')->isValid()) {
        try {
            $file = $request->file('input_img');
            $name = rand(11111, 99999) . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $request->file('input_img')->move("fotoupload", $name);
        } catch (Illuminate\Filesystem\FileNotFoundException $e) {

        }
    }
}
```

Image was successfully uploaded but the code threw an exception :

> FileNotFoundException in MimeTypeGuesser.php line 123

The file is there any fault in my code or is it a bug  in laravel 5.4, can anyone help me solve the problem ?

My view code:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="{{url('admin/post/insert')}}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="imageInput">File input</label>
        <input data-preview="#preview" name="input_img" type="file" id="imageInput">
        <img class="col-sm-6" id="preview"  src="">
        <p class="help-block">Example block-level help text here.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">submit</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Share your view?

Comment: @Niklesh ok bro i added view now

Comment: After moving the file you need to save() it.

Answer (score 48):

Try this code. This will solve your problem.

```
public function fileUpload(Request $request) {
    $this->validate($request, [
        'input_img' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
    ]);

    if ($request->hasFile('input_img')) {
        $image = $request->file('input_img');
        $name = time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $destinationPath = public_path('/images');
        $image->move($destinationPath, $name);
        $this->save();

        return back()->with('success','Image Upload successfully');
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this one, it adds validation.

Answer (score 24):

You can use it by easy way, through `store` method in your controller

like the below

#### First, we must create a form with file input to let us upload our file.

```
{{Form::open(['route' => 'user.store', 'files' => true])}}

{{Form::label('user_photo', 'User Photo',['class' => 'control-label'])}}
{{Form::file('user_photo')}}
{{Form::submit('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-success'])}}

{{Form::close()}}
```

#### Here is how we can handle file in our controller.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class UserController extends Controller
{

  public function store(Request $request)
  {

  // get current time and append the upload file extension to it,
  // then put that name to $photoName variable.
  $photoName = time().'.'.$request->user_photo->getClientOriginalExtension();

  /*
  talk the select file and move it public directory and make avatars
  folder if doesn't exsit then give it that unique name.
  */
  $request->user_photo->move(public_path('avatars'), $photoName);

  }
}
```

That’s it. Now you can save the `$photoName` to the database as a `user_photo` field value. You can use `asset(‘avatars’)` function in your view and access the photos.

Answer (score 7):

A good logic for your application could be something like:

```
 public function uploadGalery(Request $request){
      $this->validate($request, [
        'file' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,bmp,gif,svg|max:2048',
      ]);
      if ($request->hasFile('file')) {
        $image = $request->file('file');
        $name = time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $destinationPath = public_path('/storage/galeryImages/');
        $image->move($destinationPath, $name);
        $this->save();
        return back()->with('success','Image Upload successfully');
      }

    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the following code:

```
$imageName = time().'.'.$request->input_img->getClientOriginalExtension();
$request->input_img->move(public_path('fotoupload'), $imageName);
```

Comment: You should try to provide an explanation along with code.

Answer (score 4):

```
public function store()
{
    $this->validate(request(), [
        'title' => 'required',
        'slug' => 'required',
        'file' => 'required|image|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png,gif'
    ]);

    $fileName = null;
    if (request()->hasFile('file')) {
        $file = request()->file('file');
        $fileName = md5($file->getClientOriginalName() . time()) . "." . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $file->move('./uploads/categories/', $fileName);    
    }

    Category::create([
        'title' => request()->get('title'),
        'slug' => str_slug(request()->get('slug')),
        'description' => request()->get('description'),
        'category_img' => $fileName,
        'category_status' => 'DEACTIVE'
    ]);

    return redirect()->to('/admin/category');
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Intervention Image is an open source PHP image handling and manipulation library**
http://image.intervention.io/

> This library provides a lot of useful features:

**Basic Examples**

```
// open an image file
$img = Image::make('public/foo.jpg');

// now you are able to resize the instance
$img->resize(320, 240);

// and insert a watermark for example
$img->insert('public/watermark.png');

// finally we save the image as a new file
$img->save('public/bar.jpg');
```

**Method chaining:**

```
$img = Image::make('public/foo.jpg')->resize(320, 240)->insert('public/watermark.png');
```

> **Tips: (In your case)** 
>     https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/file-upload-isvalid-returns-false

**Tips 1:**

```
// Tell the validator input file should be an image & check this validation
$rules = array(
  'image' => 'mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,gif,svg  // allowed type
              |required                  // is required field
              |max:2048'               // max 2MB
              |min:1024               // min 1MB
  );
// validator Rules
$validator = Validator::make($request->only('image'), $rules);

// Check validation (fail or pass)
if ($validator->fails())
{
    //Error do your staff
} else
{
    //Success do your staff
};
```

**Tips 2:**

```
   $this->validate($request, [
        'input_img' => 
                 'required
                  |image
                  |mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg
                  |max:1024',
    ]);
```

**Function:**

```
function imageUpload(Request $request) {

   if ($request->hasFile('input_img')) {  //check the file present or not
       $image = $request->file('input_img'); //get the file
       $name = "//what every you want concatenate".'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension(); //get the  file extention
       $destinationPath = public_path('/images'); //public path folder dir
       $image->move($destinationPath, $name);  //mve to destination you mentioned 
       $image->save(); //
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($request->hasFile('input_img')) {
    if($request->file('input_img')->isValid()) {
        try {
            $file = $request->file('input_img');
            $name = time() . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();

            $request->file('input_img')->move("fotoupload", $name);
        } catch (Illuminate\Filesystem\FileNotFoundException $e) {

        }
    } 
}
```

or follow
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/image-upload-file-does-not-working
or
https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5-3/episodes/12

Answer (score 1):

i think better to do this

```
    if ( $request->hasFile('file')){
        if ($request->file('file')->isValid()){
            $file = $request->file('file');
            $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $file->move('images' , $name);
            $inputs = $request->all();
            $inputs['path'] = $name;
        }
    }
    Post::create($inputs);
```

actually **images** is folder that laravel make it automatic and **file** is name of the input and here  we store name of the image in our path column in the table and store image in public/images directory

Answer (score 1):

```
// get image from upload-image page 
public function postUplodeImage(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
  // check validtion for image or file
        'uplode_image_file' => 'required|image|mimes:jpg,png,jpeg,gif,svg|max:2048',
    ]);
// rename image name or file name 

    $getimageName = time().'.'.$request->uplode_image_file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $request->uplode_image_file->move(public_path('images'), $getimageName);
    return back()
        ->with('success','images Has been You uploaded successfully.')
        ->with('image',$getimageName);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code will store the image in database.

```
$('#image').change(function(){
        // FileReader function for read the file.
        let reader = new FileReader();
        var base64;
        reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]); 

        //Read File
        let filereader = new FileReader();
        var selectedFile = this.files[0];

        // Onload of file read the file content
        filereader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent) {
            base64 = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
            $("#pimage").val(JSON.stringify(base64));
        };

        filereader.readAsDataURL(selectedFile); 
 });
```

HTML content should be like this.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 user_frm form-group">
        <input id="image" type="file" class="inputMaterial" name="image">        
        <input type="hidden" id="pimage" name="pimage" value="">
        <span class="bar"></span>
    </div>
```

Store image data in database like this:

```
//property_image longtext(database field type)

 $data= array(
      'property_image' => trim($request->get('pimage'),'"')
 );
```

Display image:

```
<img src="{{$result->property_image}}" >
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        public function ImageUplode(Request $request) {
            if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
    
                $file      = $request->file('image');
                $filename  = $file->getClientOriginalName();
                $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $picture =  $request['code'].'.jpg';

                //move image to public/image folder

                $file->move(public_path('imgage'), $picture);

                // image uplode function Succesfully saved message 

                return response()->json(["message" => "Image Uploaded Succesfully"]);
            }
            else {
                return response()->json(["message" => "Select image first."]);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

In Laravel 5.4, you can use `guessClientExtension`