# How to fix "Call to a member function store() on null"?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm setting up an image upload option to a folder. What caused and how do I fix this error?

PHP in MessageController

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->image->store('comments');
}
```

HTML

```html
<form action="/api/messages" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    Select image to upload: 
    <input id="fileToUpload" name="fileToUpload" type="file"> 
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Upload Image">
</form>
```

I'm expecting output 200, but getting server error 500.

Comment: Your name of file is not same at both places

Comment: Use this: `request()->fileToUpload->store('comments');`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [laravel 5.4 upload image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42755302/laravel-5-4-upload-image)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are not referencing the image file correctly in the request. Instead, please try doing this:

```php
$request->file('fileToUpload')->store('comments');
```