# Facing problem when uploading image using laravel API with Nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I am new in nuxt.js. I am trying to upload image using Laravel API but I am facing some errors. I have selected the image file in the file input and when I click the submit button,it shows "Image fled is Required"

**error is**

```
{message: "The given data was invalid.",…}
errors: {image: ["The image field is required."]}
message: "The given data was invalid."
```

**my Nuxt View Code**

```
    <template>
        <v-row justify="center">
            <v-col cols="12" sm="6">
                <form @submit.prevent="submit">
                    <v-card ref="form" >
                        <v-card-text>
                            <h2 class="text-center"> Register</h2>
                            <v-divider class="mt-3"></v-divider>
                            <v-col cols="12" sm="12">
                                <v-text-field  v-model.trim="form.name" type="text" label="Name" outlined autocomplete="off"></v-text-field>
                                <small class="form-text red--text" v-if="errors.name">{{errors.name[0]}}</small>
                            </v-col>
                            <v-file-input  v-model.trim="form.image" type="file" label="image" outlined 
 autocomplete="off"></v-file-input>
                            <small class="form-text red--text" v-if="errors.image">{{errors.image[0]}}</small>
                        </v-col>
                    </v-card-text>
                    <v-card-actions>
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <v-btn rounded type="submit" color="primary" dark>Register</v-btn>
                        </div>
                    </v-card-actions>
                </v-card>
            </form>
        </v-col>
    </v-row>
    </template>
    < script >
      export default {
    
        data() {
          return {
            form: {
              name: '',
              image: '',
    
    
            }
          }
        },
        methods: {
          async submit() {
            await this.$axios.$post('/Businessregister', this.form)
            this.$router.push('/')
          }
    
    
        }
      }
    
      <
      /script>
```

**Laravel API**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function() {
Route::post('/Businessregister', 'RegisterController@register')->name('Businessregister');

});
```

Comment: @Al-Amin do you know how to fix this error

Comment: I have no idea currently, you might get some idea from here [laravel,nuxt.js,image_upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63269669/how-upload-an-image-in-nuxt-js-and-laravel-7)